# Row of flushed IMG blocks in CSS

Tags: html, css, image

What I'm attempting to do is probably best explained with a crudely mocked-up image:
[image: Problem example]

That is, in a row there are 'blocks' of three flush images. The top two next to each other, then another underneath them both. **There is zero gap between the images**.

I've found a way that appears to work in Firefox, but generates gaps in IE:

```
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 3px;">
  <img src="1.png" style="float:left;"/>
  <img src="2.png" />
  <img src="3.png" />
</div>
```

Excuse the inline styles, they're for testing only. It'd be nice to 1. not have to float: left on a load of things, and 2. not have to specify a sensible margin between them. Any 'natural' margin would do just fine.

There must be a better way than this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Here's a way of avoiding custom margins: [Perfectly justified CSS grid technique using inline-block](http://code.jelmerdemaat.nl/2012/perfectly-justified-css-grid-technique-using-inline-block/)

Answer (score 1):

How about to use like this?

```
img{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -3px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
img:last-child{
    display: block;
    width: 43px;

}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qnUPg/1/)

Comment: You can remove the below space with setting margin [demo3](http://jsfiddle.net/qnUPg/2/)

Comment: That has gaps between all the images, which is the opposite of what I need. Setting a negative margin below feels dirty - I could just do that to what I already have.

Comment: left floated elements need -4px margin to remove gap.

Answer (score 0):

For the div, set the line-height to 0.

```
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 3px; width:100px; line-height:0">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" style="float:left;"/>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/50/" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/50/" />
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3g2W/).

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3ELz4/2/)**

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;   
    display: inline-block;   
    border: 1px solid black;


}
img:last-child{
    display: block;
    width:auto;
    margin:-5px 0;


}
```

Comment: Looks like there's still gaps between the top two. All should be flush to each other, with no gaps.